# Smarty: Restart {cycle} using nested {sections}

Tags: smarty

I am trying to generate background colors for multiple tables that are contained withing a `{section} ... {/section}` block, but if I don't give names to the `{cycle}` functions, the cycle is continued, not restarted the next time it is encountered. The same problem occurs when I use named cycles and the same named cycle repeats in a section.

Example:

```
{section name=i loop=$tables}
    <table>
        {section name=j loop=$tables[i].data}
           <tr class="{cycle name=bgcolor values='odd_row,even_row'}">
               ..
               ..
               ..
           </tr>
        {/section}
    </table>
{/section}
```

How can I get the `{cycle}` to reset its self on each iteration of `{section name=j}`? Is it possible to compose names in Smarty? (use something like `{cycle name=bgcolor.$i}`)

Note: I have the same issue on another page which is included multiple times in a single .tpl and every time it shows a table, the background color cycle *continues* from where it left instead of resetting its self. I understand this is normal behavior (since there is no way for Smarty to know where my cycle begins), but I would like to change it.

Answer (score 3):

Used `reset=true` like this:

```
{section name=i loop=$tables}
    <table>
        {cycle name=bgcolor print=false reset=true values='odd_row,even_row'}
        {section name=j loop=$tables[i].data}
            <tr class="{cycle name=bgcolor values='odd_row,even_row'}">
                ..
                ..
                ..
            </tr>
        {/section}
    </table>
{/section}
```